# Trying to get rid of Cross-Site Scripting (XXS) vulnerablity in code

Tags: php, html

I have not messed with HTML or PHP much until recently for this class. My task is to use a vulnerability tool to diagnosis the problems then try to fix them. I found that the highest alert is a Cross-Site Scripting (XXS) alert. I have read on this vulnerability but find it rather confusing in telling me what I actually need to do. The code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Form Login</title>
</head>

<body OnLoad="document.main.username.focus();">



<table >
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">    
<h4>Enter your Username and Email Address to continue</h4> 
</td>
</tr>
<!-- create the main form with an input text box named uid and a password text box named mypassword -->
<form name="main" method="post" action="authcheck.php"> 
<tr> 
<td>username:</td> 
<td><input name="username" type="text" size="50"></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>Email Address:</td> 
<td><input name="emailadd" type="text" size="50"></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

The next program the one above refers to is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>User Authenticate </title>
</head>
<body> 

<?php

    // Retrieve Post Data
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["emailadd"];


         // Set the session information
         session_start();  
         $_SESSION['appusername'] = $username; 
         $_SESSION['appemail'] = $email;

 // Display the Session information
 echo "<h3> Session Data  </h3>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>
        <td>Username </td>
        <td> Email </td>
      </tr>";
echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $_SESSION['appusername'] . "</td>";
echo  "<td>" . $_SESSION['appemail']. "</td>";
echo   "</tr>";     
 echo "</table>";      

// Provide a button to logout

echo "<form name='logout' method='post' action='logout.php'> 
<input name='btnsubmit' type='submit' value='Logout'> 
</form>";     

?>
</body>
</html>
```

This program is generated when I press the submit button.

I am really just trying to find out what I should be trying to do to fix this error. Thanks

Comment: um you need to provide more code and what error you are getting exactly ... what tool is checking this?

Comment: I am using a Vulnerability Tool called ZAP

Comment: @RandyGilman like ZAP from OWASP?

Comment: Yes that is the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are printing out the variables here:

```
echo "<tr>
      <td>" . $_SESSION['appusername'] . "</td>";
echo  "<td>" . $_SESSION['appemail']. "</td>";
echo   "</tr>";
```

In order to do that, you need to remove HTML tags, and replace them with entites. To do that you need to, at the very least:

```
$username = htmlentites($_POST["username"]);
$email = htmlentities($_POST["emailadd"]);
```

You should, however do even more than that, using filter_var.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp :

```
$username = htmlentites($_POST["username"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
{
  //Bad email, so something else.
  die('...');
}
$email = $_POST["emailadd"];
```

Comment: I sanitized the username and added if statment but I keep getting a Cross Site Scripting (reflected) now. This is better than before because I had 2 alerts but now I just have the one. Any Idea what the reflected part means?

Comment: @RandyGilman are you still having issues? If so, edit/update your question with the current code.

Comment: Sorry forgot to update, that fixed it no more alerts. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are not sanitizing the username or password in anyway before writing it to that table.

Comment: Ok I will try searching how to sanitize the username and password.

Comment: You might also look into input validation. You basically want to prevent any unwanted code execution. In the pages you provided above, a user could pass in javascript or php to the username or password field which would then be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Sanitize your `$username` and `$email` variables using

```
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailadd']);
```

or

```
$username = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
$email = htmlentities($_POST['emailadd']);
```

`htmlentities();` replaces all characters with a HTML variant while `htmlspecialchars();` replaces a few amount of characters.

Note that this is the most basic form of sanitizing your POST data. You can check out this [filter function](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) for more "complex" sanitizing and validation.

Comment: Where is the proper place to put in the code because I put it in there right after it asked the user to input them and it will not load?

Comment: @RandyGilman replace it with the code you under the `// Retrieve Post Data`